# Add phone in form field & post values to database

Tags: php, mysql

**original code as below**

**signup.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $uname = trim($_POST['txtuname']);
    $email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtpass']);
    $cpass = trim($_POST['txtcpass']);
    $code = md5(uniqid(rand()));

    $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    /* some code in middle */
        if($reg_user->register($uname,$email,$upass, $code))
        {           
            $id = $reg_user->lasdID();      
            $key = base64_encode($id);
            $id = $key;
```

**class.usr**

```
public function register($uname,$email,$upass, $code)
    {
        try
        {                           
            $password = md5($upass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass, tokenCode) 
                                                         VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
            $stmt->execute();   
            return $stmt;
        }
```

**html form**

```
<form>
<input id="pass2" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="confirm Password" name="txtcpass" required />
</form>
```

i am trying to add new textfield [phone] for form and post the values in database.
i created column name as "phone", i changed some code as below :

```
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
if($reg_user->register($uname,$email,$upass, $code, $phone))

public function register($uname,$email,$upass, $code, $phone)
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass, tokenCode, phone) 
                                                         VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code, phone)");
        $stmt->bindparam("phone",$phone);
```

but it did't worked for me, i am newbie in php& mysql.

**error** :

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokenssorry , Query could no execute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
 VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code, phone)");
```

Should be

```
 VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code, :phone)");
```

You forgot `:` in front of `phone`

Comment: now i am getting this error : `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'phone' in 'field list'sorry , Query could no execute...` , but column `phone` exists in database

Comment: @user5348fh8y5: Did you also correct the same typo when binding the parameter?

Comment: `$stmt->bindparam("phone",$phone);` you need to put `:` here also

Comment: @David Thanks a lot for support.....